# How to query sibling rules from a Bazel rule

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I would like to be able to do the following in a Bazel BUILD file:

```
alpha(
  name = "hello world",
  color = "blue"
)

beta(
  name = "hello again"
)
```

Where `alpha` and `beta` are custom rules. I want `beta` to be able to access the `color` attribute of the `alpha` rule, **without adding a label attribute**. In Bazel query, I can do something like this:

`bazel query 'kind(beta, siblings(kind(alpha, //...)))'`

which gives me the `beta` which is side by side to `alpha`. Can I achieve the same somehow from within the implementation function of the `beta` rule?

```py
def _beta_rule_impl(ctx):
  # This does not exist, I wish it did: ctx.siblings(kind='alpha')
```

I've seen this been done with a label like this

```
beta(
  name = "hello again",
  alpha_link = ":hello world" # explicitly linking
)
```

but I find this a bit verbose, especially since there is a sibling query support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the question is formulated, the answer is no. It is not possible.

Bazel design philosophy is to be explicit about target dependencies. [Providers mechanism](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#providers) is meant to provide the access to the dependency graph information during the analysis phase.

It is difficult to tell what is the actual use case is. Using [Aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) might be the answer.

Comment: Thank you Konstantin, I was afraid this would be the case. I will use Aspects. I guess I jumped to conclusions because the CLI supports siblings, I expected the rule API would support it too.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I'm trying to get a `genrule` to call a `test` rule before proceeding:

```
genrule(
    name = "generate_buf_image",
    srcs = [":protos", "cookie"],
    outs = ["buf-image.json"],
    cmd = "$(location //third_party/buf:cas_buf_image) //example-grpc/proto/v1:proto_backwards_compatibility_check $(SRCS) >$(OUTS)",
    tools = [
        "//third_party/buf:cas_buf_image",
        "@buf",
    ],
)
```

If `cas_buf_image.sh` has `ls -l "example-grpc/proto/v1" >&2`, it shows:

```
… cookie -> …/example-grpc/proto/v1/cookie
… example.proto -> …/example-grpc/proto/v1/example.proto
```

IOW, examining what `example-grpc/proto/v1/cookie` is linked to and `cd`ing to its directory then performing the `git` commands should work.